# Why don't Democrats encourage Christine Blasey Ford to file a criminal complaint against Kavanaugh in Maryland to trigger a local investigation?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

[This analysis](https://lawandcrime.com/high-profile/maryland-authorities-say-they-will-investigate-kavanaugh-if-ford-files-complaint/) indicates that a complaint should trigger an investigation in this case.  In particular, there's good reason to believe there is no statute of limitations in effect:

> Maryland’s former deputy attorney general Thiru Vignarajah. In a
>   Twitter thread posted on Friday night after the joint letter was made
>   public, Vignarajah noted:
>
> For those looking at Md statute of limitations (SOL), the closest
>   thing to what we today call attempted first-degree rape was, in 1982,
>   assault with intent to rape, which is a felony to which no SOL
>   applies. (Not to be confused with the misdemeanor of attempt to rape.)

...

> Vignarajah also cited a Maryland Supreme Court case which describes
>   the difference between the felony and misdemeanor versions of the
>   similarly-named sex crimes in question.
>
> Christensen v. Maryland notes, “If an attempt to commit a rape
>   proceeds to a degree whereby it is tantamount to an assault upon the
>   victim, the offense becomes the felony of assault with intent to rape,
>   but if the attempt to rape falls short of an assault, the offense
>   remains a common law misdemeanor.”

Wouldn't a complaint have resulted in the subpoenae she was seeking?  We know that she has chosen to publically describe the events, testify under oath, and call for an investigation, so this would be "victim led" and wouldn't risk revictimization.  From [Washington Examiner](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/christine-blasey-fords-lawyers-blast-fbi-not-interested-in-seeking-the-truth):

> "An FBI supplemental background investigation that did not include an
>   interview of Dr. Christine Blasey Ford - nor the witnesses who
>   corroborate her testimony - cannot be called an investigation," Ford's
>   lawyers wrote in a statement to reporters. "We are profoundly
>   disappointed that after the tremendous sacrifice she made in coming
>   forward, those directing the FBI investigation were not interested in
>   seeking the truth."

Comment: I do not believe this should be closed. There may be objective consequences of such an action, and if so then these can be described in an answer.

Comment: This possibly belongs on [law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com), in terms of the legalities involved. The bit about motivations is off-topic either place. And actually, it's [already there](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32334/are-there-legal-reasons-for-christine-blasey-ford-not-to-file-a-criminal-complai) and about to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Jared Smith: Why are motivations off topic?  Democrats wanted a more thorough investigation that would take longer.  Politically, they would like to block the confirmation by any legal and ethical means.  This method offers a way to do it, so there must be some reason they are not.  On law.stackexchange I ask if there is a legal reason (they're not closing it).  Here I'm asking if there's a political one, or if a personal reason is blocking the political move.

Comment: @user1441998 if you're asking whether the *Democrats* have a political advantage/disadvantage for pursuing strategy x, then that's on topic. But your question is about the internal motivations of *one individual person*, whose interests may not align precisely with the benefit of a particular political party, compounded by the personal nature of the situation. *That* is purely speculative. Here or there.

Comment: @user1441998, you ask "why are motivations off topic" - Discussion of motivations of others is generally speculative (unless the "other" has publicized their motivation). Speculation is strongly discouraged on this site. If you want to speculate there are plenty of other sites to go to.

Comment: @BobE, Jared Smith, JJJ, Machavity: I'm asking for a strategic analysis.  That involves estimating the goals of individuals/groups and evaluating the effectiveness of various tactics they may use to achieve them, including the consequences and responses of other individuals/groups, which depends on estimates of their goals.  Analyzing motivation is essential to politics and necessarily involves speculation because goals may be more or less public.

Comment: @BobE, Jared Smith, JJJ, Machavity: In this case, Democrats and CBF have relatively obvious goals that they have been mostly direct about or can be inferred from their public feminist and pro-choice platform:  the fullest possible investigation, the longest possible delay of confirmation.  The tactic identified seems to be effective towards those goals, and I'm asking what downside is preventing them from pursuing it.

Comment: @BobE, Jared Smith, JJJ, Machavity: Moreover, CBF (in virtue of public testimony in a senate confirmation hearing) is a political actor, so her individual motivations are relevant here.  IE, we could reasonably ask "what reasons would she have for lying?" or "what reasons would she have for minimizing her romantic involvement with squi?"

Comment: Your definition of "political actor" is overly generous. Is there something that she **said** that suggests that she is a political actor, or is the fact that she testified before a senate committee define her as a political actor ?  Lastly, I don't remember Squi even being brought up during the hearing, or for that matter in the question or comments here.

Comment: @BobE: She decided to testify to the Senate when she learned of a likely nomination to the Supreme Court, instead of filing criminal charges (especially long ago, when it could have protected other women and possibly prevented him from becoming a federal judge).  Those are political decisions.  [Here](https://theintercept.com/2018/09/27/live-christine-blasey-ford-brett-kavanaugh-testify/) is a discussion of her Squi testimony.

Comment: Actually she decided to tell her congressman confidentially when she read that BK was on the short list, she obviously did **not** decide to testify before the Senate then - first part of your explanation is inaccurate.  Second part of that sentence demonstrates fundamental lack of awareness as to why women that are victimized don't initiate criminal charges - they have learned from experience and the male dominated culture that unless they have rock solid eyewitnesses they will not be believed to the point that a credible investigation would be initiated. As for Squi, so what.

Comment: @BobE - she decided to take action based on a political nomination, not based on personal circumstances. She decided to tell a politician and then testify publicly to the Senate instead of filing a criminal complaint (aren't those confidential, at least wrt identities, in this kind of case?) -- those are political decisions with political outcomes. I'm certainly aware that sometimes criminal complaints aren't investigated and sometimes that deters reporting and that these dynamics have a gendered component that many people feel is unfair to women.

Comment: @BobE - but I see no reason why public testimony to the Senate on national television would not have the same problem. And once you've decided to do that, I see no reason not to also file the criminal complaint (my OP question, in fact). In any case, the analysis I linked indicated that the local police will investigate if they receive a complaint. There is no denying that not reporting puts other women in danger, whatever the reason. Many criminal complaints are in fact investigated, and even if they aren't there is a record that can be helpful in future cases that have better evidence.

Comment: @BobE - I didn't ask about Squi, I only said it would be relevant to do so here. Don't you find it interesting that she dated a guy ("for months") that was mentioned by name on Kavanaugh's calendar and was the sole connection between them? Isn't it interesting that you weren't even aware of that because of how she answered the question? Surely a criminal investigation would subpoena Squi to learn what he could remember about situations where Kavanaugh and Ford may have interacted.

Comment: Ever been groped, ever have a guy try to unbutton your blouse, ever have a guy try to put his hand up your thigh. Do you think that any of these are **not** assaults?  Do you really think that a police complaint would been taken seriously today (or 30 years ago)?  Do you think that the police would expend any time or effort to investigate these straight forward assaults, that I can assure you are occurring hundreds of times a week on college campuses today?  Police are way too busy chasing drugs, and guns, etc. to be bothered by a little heavy **unwanted** pawing. The guys know it.

Comment: @BobE - There's a reasonable chance that a complaint would lead to an investigation even now (especially because of how high profile the case is now). The accusation is much more serious than groping, and even some groping is criminally prosecuted. There's no statute of limitations for the crime she described, the local police are on record saying they'd investigate if there were a complaint, there are at least 2 dozen parties that could be subpoenaed that the FBI didn't interview.

Comment: @BobE - It could have resulted in the investigation that Ford and Democrats said they wanted, and would have contributed to the politically useful delay and controversy they sought. If no investigation did result, that in itself would serve to further the political point that Ford/Democrats/MeToo was pursuing by testifying. I see no downside from their point of view - that's my question.

Comment: The crime she described: I **thought** I was going to be raped, I **thought** he might accidentally kill me. - Actual crime: put his hands on me, pushed me on bed.  BK could be charged with actual crime, but not with what she **thought** might happen. So now tell me how much more serious that is versus groping and 'pu**y grabbing. LEO should not care  who the guy is today. My point is that they would not have seriously investigated  30 years ago, and they wouldn't seriously investigate today

Comment: @BobE, see OP: "an attempt to commit a rape proceeds to a degree whereby it is tantamount to an assault upon the victim, the offense becomes the felony of assault with intent to rape," "a felony to which no SOL applies."  the police have said they would investigate if she files a complaint.  and if they don't, all the more visibility for MeToo.

Comment: Just dissassemble that language, "assault upon the victim" - and apply the elements required: Intent to do harm, Reasonable apprehension, actual harm. Prosecutors must prove **all three** elements. CBF never claimed actual harm, consequentially (legally) assault could not be proven.  So what you are left with is CBF being apprehensive because she **thought** she was going to be raped. LEO isn't going to investigate based on that (not then and not today)

Comment: I'm pretty sure assault is any time you touch someone when they've made it clear they don't want you to. Certainly putting your hand on someone's mouth so they can't breathe qualifies. Tho I agree this case couldn't be proven, I believe it would be likely investigated for the reasons stated, with the attendant political benefits to Democrats.

Comment: the common law definition of assault, not substantially different from any US jurisdiction (according to [this](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/assault)): "an intentional act by one person that creates an apprehension in another of an imminent harmful or offensive contact."  so not even contact is required, but since that was alleged it would also be [battery](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/battery).

Answer (score 3):

The letter in the linked analysis says that the statute of limitation is up, so that is likely the reason. There is no point in making a criminal complaint that will not lead anywhere because of the statute of limitation.

While the linked analysis makes it seem that way, the [letter](http://www.mymcpnews.com/2018/09/28/police-and-states-attorney-response-to-montgomery-county-house-delgations-delegations-request-to-open-criminal-investigation-against-judge-brett-kavanaugh/) isn't actually a direct suggestion for "going forward" with a criminal complaint in this specific case, but a general "we do take sexual assault seriously and prosecute it when we can".

It does not say that "they are prepared to investigate the sexual assault allegations against [...] Kavanaugh–if Christine Blasey Ford is willing to file a criminal complaint" as alleged in the analysis.

On a more general note, the letter also lays out that the decision to report is a personal and difficult decision, and that revictimization is a part of that.

Comment: I edited the question to quote the analysis, which shows that her allegations amount to felony assault with intent to rape, which has no statute of limitations.  Also, she has already publically reported the crime, testified under oath, and called for an investigation, so it is not a matter of revictimization.

Comment: "statute of limitation is up" - citation required

Comment: @JJJ those are current laws, but we need the 1982 laws.  In the link sited in the OP, Vignarajah provides those, showing that if the attempt included an assault, it was a felony with no SOL.